# Array Sum Method

Tags: java, arrays

My method will sum the elements (or components or whatever you would call them) of an array. The `a.length()` part of the following code doesn't work though.

```
public double ArraySum(double[] a)
{
    double sum = 0;
    double Element;
    for(Element = 0; Element < a.length(); Element++)
    {
        sum = sum + a[Element];
    }
}
```

Could anyone tell me why the .length method suddenly doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because arrays have a `length` field, not a length method. And, by convention, Java variable names start with a lower case letter (and so do method names; `ArraySum` should probably be `getArraySum` or `sumArray`). There's no need to use a `double` as your loop counter and you could use `+=`. Change

```
double Element;
for(Element = 0; Element < a.length(); Element++)
{
    sum = sum + a[Element];
}
```

to something like

```
for(int element = 0; element < a.length; element++) {
    sum += a[element];
}
```

**or** you could use an enhanced [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) like

```
for(double element : a) { //<-- for each element in the array.
    sum += element;       //<-- add the element to the sum.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see. You are a bit confused with that length thing. Even I was when I started with java.

`length` is a variable or field in case of arrays but `length()` is a method in case of strings.

Suppose we have an Array `p` and String `q`.

To get the lengths:

- p.length
- q.length()

So that's the difference.