# Creating a class that squares and sums an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to write a class method that squares, then sums an array but I've no clue how to advance from here. I also don't know if I should split the method to square it and then another to sum it or if i can actually combine them into this one. Here's what I've come up with so far...though its not much.

```
public int sqSum(){
    for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)

        int sqSum = array[i] * array[i];

    return sqSum;
}
```

Comment: Just think about the problem some more... You are declaring & overriding one variable. You are not summing / adding onto anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array Sum Method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35967397/array-sum-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are actually declaring the same `sqSum` variable again and again without summing.

So declare it outside the `for` loop as shown below:

```
public int sqSum(){
    int sqSum =0;//declare it outside loop and use the same

    for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
       sqSum = sqSum + array[i] * array[i]; //add each product to previous sqSum

    return sqSum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I got you right:

```
public int sqSum() {
    int sqSum = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
        sqSum += array[i] * array[i];

    return sqSum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use java 8 stream api, like `int sqSum = Arrays.stream(array).map(i -> i * i).sum()`.